# Function f:X->$\Re$ when X is a measurable set. Can f be unmeasurable?

Tags: real-analysis

As the title states, I need to find the functions that aren't measurable, but have a measurable set as a source (because the sigma-algebra on my space A, is P(A) ). I know that every non-zero-measure set has unmeasurable set in it, but how can I describe the functions that their image is those unmeasurable sets?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220692/examples-of-measurable-and-non-measurable-functions

Comment: @Paquarian so the indicator function for all of those unmeasurable sets are unmeasurable functions? Are there any other functions?

Comment: When you define a function, you define it from some space $X$ to for example $\mathbb{R}.$ To check if the function is measurable, $X$ has to have some sigma algebra. And by definition of a sigma algebra, $X$ itself has to be in that sigma algebra. So any "non-measurable" function is defined on a measurable set in a way.

Comment: Also, look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6494/example-of-a-non-measurable-function